# Who provides Custom Object Detection

Tags: google-api, microsoft-custom-vision, amazon-machine-learning

Are Microsoft the only company who provided custom object detection? They have limit on 100 projects looking for a more scaleable provider.

Comment: I have not used it so far with the custom labels. Would amazon cover your requirements? https://aws.amazon.com/de/rekognition/custom-labels-features/